# Strange error while using page types

Tags: publishing, event-system

I am trying to create a page using a page type but I am ending up with the below error always:

> An error occured while processing the change for page: SOME_PAGE_NAME (tcm:SOMEID). Check the error for detailed information. 
>   **It is not possible to paste a shared item.**

Almost the same error **It is not possible to paste a shared item.** appear when I am trying to save the page type after modifying. I have commented all my event system dll registration in Tridion config file to check if it is because of event system but no luck.

The version of the Tridion is 2013 SP1 and it is happening in only one publication not for all publication page types.

Could anybody let me know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm the version of Tridion and Experience manager that you are using? Can you check the content delivery webservice for additional logs and update your question?

Comment: The version of Tridion is 2013 SP1 and also it is happening for page types related to only one publication and not for other publications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a Page based on a Page Type, the system will create a copy of the Page which acts as Page Type and (optionally) of the Components used on that Page.

The error indicates that one of these source items (Page Type or its Components) is Shared in the context where the new Page and/or its Components are created.  You will probably find more details in the Tridion Event Log on the CM Server.

Frankly, I don't see why that should be an issue, but a work-around can be to localize the Page Type and/or its Components in that context.

Comment: This I get from the Event Log at PageEventHandler of my Event system: Tridion.ContentManager.InvalidActionException: It is not possible to paste a shared item.

Comment: How does the Stack Trace look?